# ionic 1 with Firebase 3 get key from snapshot?

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

```
firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid + '/cars')

 .on('value', function(snapshot) {
    $scope.cars = snapshot.val();
    console.log('snapshot', JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()));
  });
```

I can pull all the data I need except, for the key value set by Firebase ( -KVChuDgmbogzH2bKm1A ).  It is being logged to the console. But I can't display it. I have tried cars.key, key, $id, cars.$id

```
<div ng-repeat="car in cars">     

 <p>item key: {{car.key}}</p> <- this I can't get 
        <h2>{{car.color}}</h2><- this is fine
         <p>{{car.motor}}</p><-  this is fine
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data from Firebase is being loaded asynchronously. By the time the data is loaded, Angular isn't ready for it anymore.

So you need to tell AngularJS that it needs to update the HTML. The easiest way to do this is by wrapping the updating of the scope in a `$timeout()` call:

```
firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid + '/cars')    
 .on('value', function(snapshot) { $timeout() {
    $scope.cars = snapshot.val();
    console.log('snapshot', JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()));
 })});
```

**Update**

You seem to be looking for the `key` of each snapshot.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, car) in cars">     

 <p>item key: {{key}}</p> <- this I can't get 
    <h2>{{car.color}}</h2><- this is fine
     <p>{{car.motor}}</p><-  this is fine
```

At this point I recommend switching to using AngularFire, which solves many problems for you.

Comment: Thank you for the very fast reply. Frank. But $timeout is not helping my issue.  All of the JSON data is being returned, as I can view it all in the console.  My html is updating as expected except for the id                                                    <p>item key: {{car.key}}</p> <- this I can't get this returns nothing I need it to return -KVChuDgmbogzH2bKm1A 
        <h2>{{car.color}}</h2><-  returns blue
         <p>{{car.motor}}</p><-   returns v8   Sorry if I didn't word my first question well, i'm new here and to angular and firebase.

Comment: I added a sample for that too. Note that while your problem maybe wasn't solved with my initial reply, the `$timeout()` is needed too.

Comment: THANK YOU FRANK !  <div ng-repeat="(key, car) in cars">   I didn't call key !